# Arbitrary Intersection of Bounded Sets Is Bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\{C_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ be an arbitrary collection of bounded sets in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider $C=\bigcap_{i\in I}C_i$. Moreover, let each $C_i$ be bounded by $B_{r_i}$, where $B_{r_i}$ is the ball of radius $r_i$ centered at the origin.

It is often showed that $C$ is bounded by letting $r=\max\left\{r_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ and arguing that $C$ is bounded by $B_r$.

I do not buy this.

Consider the collection of bounded sets $\left\{B_{r_i}\right\}_{r_i>0}$. Then $r$ does not exist.

Am I missing something? If not, then may I be hinted at a different way of showing that $C$ is bounded?

This is my best argument so far: "Let $x\in C$. Then $x\in C_i$ for each $i\in I$. Because each $C_i$ is bounded, it follows that $x$ is bounded." However, I have a hunch feeling that it may be too "hand-wavy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does $B_{r_i}$ bound $C$ for some $i$?

Comment: Is it okay to just say that $C$ is a subset of every $C_i$, which implies that $C$ is bounded by any $B_{r_i}$ that I wish?

Comment: @Josué Exactly. I was just about to post an answer but now that you figured it out yourself I will not.